# Searching for values inside other values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

If the value `09` from cell `C2` appears in cells `B3`/`B4`, I would like the result to be `yes` in cells `D3`/`D4`, or `no` otherwise.

The results should be a `yes` for cell `D3` and a `no` for cell `D4`:

[image: Table screenshot]

How can I write a formula to do so?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and best solution is to use the `FIND()` function to search for a value inside another value:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `C3` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down into `C3:C4`:

```dart
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(C$2,B3)),"no","yes")
```

Note that the find function returns the `#VALUE!` error if the string can't be found.

I presume you meant to say that the formula should be in column `C`. If you actually meant column `D`, the formula will work there as well.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

*Enter this array Formula in cell D3, finish with* **Crtl+Shift+Enter** & fill it down.

```
{=IFERROR(IF(INDEX($C$1:$C$2,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1:$C$2,B3)),0)),"Yes"),"No")}
```

*You get the desire results in D3 & D4.*